Estimating the standard deviation from only the mean and 95% CI
I need to generate a population of a variable which I can sample from in a Monte Carlo simulation. The only information I have on this variable is from a published paper in which the mean and 95% confidence interval (CI) are given. I do know that the sample size (n) is "large", i.e. in the thousands, and I also know that the population is normally distributed. My question: Is it possible to either 1) estimate the standard deviation, if I know n is large, or 2) is there some other way to create a population based on the 95% CI?

You can estimate the SEM from the CI. With large samples, the CI extends 1.96 times the SEM in each direction.
The relationship between SD and SEM is simple: SEM = SD/sqrt(n). If you don't know n, you can't compute a SD from a SEM.
